# Paypal Payments Pro on Sandbox return always #10001 "Internal Error"

Tags: paypal, credit-card, paypal-sandbox

I've been testing Paypal Payments Pro for a while. Switching to Sandbox I got always the error number #10001 "Internal Error".

Paypal KB is not very clear about this error and many have this issue while testing in Sandbox.
Someone says that Sandbox env is not 100% reliable, and keeps creating fake Pro accounts until they find the one that actually works.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that, following this [guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PayflowPro_Guide.pdf), I have to use one of the default CC Numbers, instead of a fake one (even though you generate CC Number through Paypal Sandbox Environment).

It took me a while to get thorought it.